# delay the execution of a js function

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function to display an image in the center of the box. However, when the image is loaded, it comes with some default style including position information. Calling the center image function is essentially happening at the same time as image loading, but it finishes before image is fully loaded. This cause the side effect of center image function to be overritten by the default style of the image, and as a result the image is not placed in the center of the box.

I am wondering if I could delay the execution of center image function to solve this. Any one tell me how to delay the execution of a js function? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the execution of a function using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), but I don't think that's what  you want, since you can listen for when an image has loaded.

```
if(image.complete) {
    // already finished loading
}else{
    image.onload=function() {
        // loaded
    };
}
```

Comment: I dont know, but can there be a race condition when setting the onload? That is, the image completes its loading right before image.onload is assigned. Would this mess things up? If so, should there be another image.complete check after you assign the onload function?

Comment: @trinithis: I doubt that could happen. JavaScript is single threaded, and this code is synchronous, so I don't think anything else could happen until this code is done. If the image finished loading while this code was running, the event would occur after this code finished executing.

Comment: Its just that while JS is single threaded, the page loader might not share the same thread.

Comment: @trinithis: It would have to wait for the code to finish executing to fire the `load` event, though, and I don't think it would update `complete` until the script was idle either.

Answer (score 0):

Call the "center image" function on the `onload` event of the `img`

```
<img src="<>" onload="centerImage()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) javascript library you can use the following code snipped to run code after all the images have loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
  //initialize after images are loaded  
});
```

Instead of "window" (all images on the page have loaded), you can also directly select an image.